# Работа уведомлений когда пользователь вне приложения

Tags: unity3d, push-уведомления, android-push-notification

Не могли бы вы помочь с такой задачей - как отправлять уведомления в фоновом режиме (с минимальной нагрузкой на устройство). Я написал код для самой отправки уведомлений(с помощью package "Mobile Notifications"), но в фоновом режиме не могу.